# Do native speakers say "you're way too late" in real life?

Tags: colloquial-language

[Google gives About 663,000 results for "you're way too late"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you%27re%20way%20too%20late%22&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&oq=%22you%27re%20way%20too%20late%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60l2.1338j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), some comes from lyrics, some are in a story. Do native speakers say it in real life?

Imagine that, it's 8 o'clock AM. My son is still sleeping who is supposed to wake up at 7 o'clock AM. So, he is late for school. I am waking him up:

> Hey, get up, **you're way too late**!

Is it natural and commonly acceptable to say it that way. Is there any situation in real life where people say it?

Comment: A person who doesn't wake up when they should is said to have _overslept_. I think most people would say "Wake up, it's eight o'clock!" or "It's late"! in those circumstances. "You're too late" would be said to someone who had missed an appointment or an opportunity through lateness.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. your comment is very helpful. How about this case, my son is late for school, which is similar to an appointment.

Comment: He was late for school = arrived after the official start time. He arrived too late for assembly (or whatever the first thing on the timetable is) = he missed out on attending it.